# Is there a search engine to show citing articles' extracts

Tags: publications, citations, google-scholar, bibliometrics, web-of-science

Sometimes we need to see what other researchers say about a specific article. Usually, I check citing articles manually then search for my specific articles in their references.

Is there a search engine that can show extracts from the citing articles. Following is an example to clarify this.

Article (1) is cited by Article (2) 
I am looking for a search engine to show that Article (2) cited Article (1) as well as to show where Article (1) was cited inside Article (2).

Comment: Such a search engine would likely be illegal, since it is hard to get permission from every publisher.

Comment: Google Scholar can’t already do this? I know Google web search does something similar.

Comment: No Google Scholar does not. In fact, all search engines have this feature implemented in their backend: this is how they discover citing articles, but I couldn't find anyone that provides that insight.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [www.semanticscholar.org](https://www.semanticscholar.org/) to see the extractions of the paper citing the specific article you want. In other words, you will see what and how other researchers use that paper, if applicable.

To do so, you need to type and search for the paper you want. You will see a section called "Citations: Publications citing this paper," and you can read the extractions from this section.

It is easy to use and free. The only limitation of this service is that it might not cover all databases as much as google scholars or other paid services. However, they are increasing their coverage day by day. In any way, it is a useful website to add your research arsenal.